# Performing feature selection with XGBoost R

Tags: r, r-caret, xgboost, feature-selection

I have created a predictive model in R. I want to do feature selection. I have read that xgboost makes it unnecessary to do variable selection but I added a variable for the past 1,2,3,4, and 5 scores. Adding each variable gave these RMSEs in a 5 fold 5 repeated cross-validation.

10.3
10.1
10
10.1
10.5

This shows that variable selection does make a difference because of the U pattern the error rate creates.

I am thinking of iterating through all new variables but that sounds inefficient. Is there a better way of doing it?

I was also thinking about doing stepwise regression and using those features. Is that a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and perform feature selection based on the feature importance score, keeping only feature whose importante exceeds a given threshold (say the mean feature importance) and try and see whether that improves the RMSE